# Drupal 7 - Retrieving certain records through Intelligent queries

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, business-intelligence

I've developed a website which offers thousands of products classified in 10-12 different categories. Each category offers number of choices which are defined through Taxonomy.

I have configured [Profile 2]: http://drupal.org/project/profile2 module which enables members to set their preferences by selecting number of choices in each category.

Now I need to send a letter to each member on daily basis offering only 5 products out of thousands according to their preferences. I also want to keep record of the products sent to each member so that each day the offered products should be next five from the previous day. When the products cycle completes it will be restarted from the beginning.

My question is: what would be the best option to complete this job and how?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a custom module and use cron to run it. You can use [taxonomy_select_nodes](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!taxonomy!taxonomy.module/function/taxonomy_select_nodes/6) module to select nodes. It also comes with a pager which you can use to maintain the order    or you can also maintain a database with uid and list of products sent everyday.